# java-library does not expose scala classes

Tags: scala, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle project that uses subprojects. One of them (common) uses an external library:

```
// common/build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
    implementation("com.example:external-lib:1.2.3")
}
```

and has a Scala class that uses types in `external-lib`.

Another subproject references common:

```
// service/build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":common"))
}
```

This works fine, but if I add the `java-library` plugin to `common` and switch `implementation` to `api`:

```
// common/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    `java-library`
}
dependencies {
    api("com.example:external-lib:1.2.3")
}
```

then the code in `service` will see the types in `external-lib` (which is expected) but not the Scala class in `common`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I used this for sub-projects to solve this issue:

```
subprojects {

  apply plugin: 'java-library'
  apply plugin: 'maven'
  apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
  apply plugin: 'scalaStyle'
  apply plugin: 'idea'

  dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: scalaVersion
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sure using `compile` would also work for me, I'm just curious why `api` behaves the way it does.